# Difference Between int (*)(...) and int (^)(...) in OS X C?

Tags: c, macos

Looking at `stdlib.h` definitions, as expanded by `gcc -E` on a hello-world program, I see, for example,

```
int heapsort(void *, size_t, size_t,
     int (*)(const void *, const void *));

int heapsort_b(void *, size_t, size_t,
     int (^)(const void *, const void *)) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.6)));
```

I don't recall ever seeing a type notation like `int(^)`. I also notice the `_b` suffix in the second declaration. Quick googling did not find anything useful (usually sending me to info about the XOR operator, also named `^`). Would someone be so kind as to explain what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is not pure C. This is an Apple extension of C (see [LLVM Blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html)), used mostly in Objective-C.

The `^` denotes a **block**. A block is a closure.

The use of blocks is similar to function pointers but a block can be defined in place, e.g.

```
void function() {
    void (^simpleBlock)(void) = ^{
       NSLog(@"This is a block");
    }

    simpleBlock();
}
```

The whole concept is rather complicated (blocks on the stack, blocks on the heap, capturing variables, retain cycles with blocks etc.) so if you are interested in this topic, you should read the official Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) first.

Comment: It is C with Apple's “blocks” extension (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)).  It is not (necessarily) Objective-C.